# What $is$ $\text{dist}^2\left( F,\mathsf{SO}(3)\right)$?

Tags: notation, calculus-of-variations

Reading some review about calculous of variations and mechanics, the following notation is very recurrent for energy density functionals

\begin{equation}
\text{dist}^p\left( F,\mathsf{SO}(N)\right),
\end{equation}

with $F$ usually in $\mathbb{R}^{N\times N}$. However I have not found a precise definition of these objects.

Comment: I would guess that it means $\mathrm{dist}^p(F,SO(N)):=\inf_{A\in SO(N)}\left\Vert F-A\right\Vert_p$ but as far as I know this is not "standard notation" and really should be defined, if used.

Comment: Let me add one more detail: Usually, you prefer to work on an inner product space (Hilbert space) and use the scalar product $\langle A, B \rangle=tr(AB^T)$ on the space of square matrices. They usually allow for easier computation of the Euler-Lagrange equations or functional derivative in this context